# Display Time Taken Search Statistics Webpart

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

I want to display time taken in brackets next to no. of search results in SharePoint 2010.

I know I can display it like that:

```
1-10 of 500 results Your search took 0.31 seconds.
```

I want to display it like

```
 1-10 of 500 results (0.31 seconds).
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the web part "Search Statistics" of your Search Center site. Just read this article, if something is unclear: [office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customize-the-search-center-site-HA010382279.aspx](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customize-the-search-center-site-HA010382279.aspx)

You might be interested in the chapter "Edit a Web Part by using its tool pane".

Good luck :)